# Use linq to select a range that overlaps another range

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains a number of 'bands', as follows:

```
var bands = new List<Band>();

bands.Add(new Band(1, 12, 1, 100, 199, 100, 292));
bands.Add(new Band(1, 5, 1, 200, 1000, 100, 292));
bands.Add(new Band(6, 6, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 210));
bands.Add(new Band(7, 7, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 192));
bands.Add(new Band(8, 8, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 178));
bands.Add(new Band(9, 9, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 167));
bands.Add(new Band(10, 10, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 158));
bands.Add(new Band(11, 11, 1, 200, 2000, 100, 150.5));
bands.Add(new Band(12, 12, 1, 200, 999, 100, 140));
bands.Add(new Band(12, 18, 3, 1000, 3000, 100, 71.3));
bands.Add(new Band(24, 24, 6, 1000, 3000, 100, 71.3));
```

The important **columns are 4 and 5** - the first band values being 100 and 199.

Presently, I have a query that selects one or more bands based on a single parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<Quote> ForAmount(int amount)
{
    return Repository.Bands
        .Where(x => amount >= x.MinAmount && amount <= x.MaxAmount)
        .YieldTerms(amount); // this does something with the selected data
}
```

However, I'd like to pull out bands that fall within a low and high range.

New signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<Quote> ForAmount(int lowAmount, int highAmount)
{
    // Query
}
```

So, for instance Low = 100 and High = 500.

Given the example high/low values, the following band would be selected (100 - 500 overlaps 100 - 199).

```
bands.Add(new Band(1, 12, 1, 100, 199, 100, 292));
```

So would the following band (100 - 500 overlaps 200 - 2000).

```
bands.Add(new Band(1, 5, 1, 200, 1000, 100, 292));
```

I'm sure this is easily done, but I've got brain fog right now, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: In your example, all bands except the last two overlap the 100-500 range, correct?

Comment: @elgonzo - yes that would be correct for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Repository.Bands
    .Where(x => x.MinAmount <= High && x.MaxAmount >= Low)
```

should do it

Comment: This would be if you needed both bounds to be between `Low` and `High`, which does not seem to be what OP wants

Comment: @Rafalon, from the question: "_I'd like to pull out bands **that fall within a low and high range**_" (emphasis mine) Saying "overlap" does not necessarily mean restriction to "partial overlap"

Comment: @elgonzo "***100 - 500 overlaps 200 - 2000***" (emphasis mine)

Comment: To clarify guys, where any bands intersects my parameter range - sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Rafalon, yeah but where do you derive that only a partial overlap is an overlap, whereas a complete overlap is not an overlap?

Comment: I understood it in the way that the intersection should not be empty, e.g. 100-300 overlaps 200-400. and 100 <= 400 && 300 >= 200 ist true, so the formula in my answer catches this case.

Comment: Oh right! I was reading `x.MaxAmount <= High && x.MinAmount >= Low`!

Comment: Just checked out a few use cases, and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrated something similar to your example in dotnet fiddle; 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHr2Nn

This should be working.

```
public static IEnumerable<Quote> ForAmount(int lowAmount, int highAmount)
{
    return Repository.Bands
        .Where(x => x.MinAmount <= highAmount && x.MinAmount >= lowAmount) 
             || (x.MaxAmount >= lowAmount && x.MaxAmount <= highAmount))
        .YieldTerms(...); // this does something with the selected data
}
```